# Share data between serializes fields

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a `ModelSerializer` class which implements some fields with `SerializerMethodField`. There are a few fields which calculates currency data according to the rates retrieved from a database if there are, otherwise from a bank API. 
With current implementation there are a lot of short queries to the database just to retrieve or check a rate. I'm thinking of reducing the number of queries by sharing already calculated data between fields.
The code will explain the idea better:

```
class CalcualteSomethingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    currency_value_1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    currency_value_2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_currency_value_1(obj):
        if obj.currency_code != 'USD':
            rate = get_rates('USD', obj.currency_code, obj.date)
            return calculation_logic1(obj.value, rate)

    def get_currency_value_2(obj):
        if obj.currency_code != 'USD':
            rate = get_rates('USD', obj.currency_code, obj.date)
            return calculation_logic2(obj.value, rate)
```

I've tried to save the rates into `self._kwargs` but it reduced a number of queries only for 5 queries.

Comment: You should use Django's [cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) for this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman seems like an option. I even didn't thought about built-in django caches.